# Trying to use switch statement insted of if else to find out which value is bigger or smaller

Tags: c#, if-statement, switch-statement

I am a beginner in learning c# (and any coding language)
I am trying to use **switch** statement instead of **if else**.

this is the working if else statement

```
  private void RunScript(int a, int b, ref object A)
  {
    if (a < b)
    {
      Print("a is smaller than b");
      Print("b is bigger than a");
    }
    else if (a > b)
    {
      Print("a is bigger than b");
      Print("b is smaller than a");
    }
    else
    {
      Print("a equals b");
    }
```

this is the switch that I am trying to do

```
 private void RunScript(double a, double b, ref object A)
      {
        double whichIsBigger = a - b;
//below is the 58th line
        switch (whichIsBigger)
        {
          case whichIsBigger < 0:
            Print("a is bigger than b");
            break;
          case whichIsBigger > 0:
            Print("a is smaller than b");
            break;
          default:
            Print("a equals b");
            break;
        }
```

It gives me this
Error (CS0151): A switch expression or case label must be a bool, char, string, integral, enum, or corresponding nullable type (line 58)

FYI, I'm trying to do this on rhinoceros3d, using the rhino common library.

and also, I've been trying to find a website or forum to learn c# where I can
ask questions like these. I ended up here.
I think that this kind of questions is pretty basic, but I can't find a
resource that can give me an answer to this problem.
I have read several posts and can't find a similar problem

If there are any sites where people can answer my questions fast like a chat room or something,
please do let me know.

Comment: Microsoft has some great [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/index) for C#. Especially for the [Switch Statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch). :)

Comment: https://www.dotnetperls.com/ is another great resource with examples for C# programming fundamentals.

Answer (score 4):

Basically, you're trying to run an evaluation in your `case` statement. You have to do the evaluation before, and use the values in your `case` statement.

If it's a `true` / `false` situation, you shouldn't use switch. Switch is generally for when there are a number of options that could be true. For example, if you had an `enum` with multiple values, and you want to do something different for each value (like `DayOfWeek.Monday`, `DayOfWeek.Tuesday`, etc). For the exact reason you're running into here.

If you really wanted, you could create an enum of `ABCompare.Bigger`, `ABCompare.Smaller`, `ABCompare.Equal` or something like that, and then `switch` on that -- but that doesn't really make sense.

Comment: TL;DR Switch statements only work on *equality*, you can't just throw a random condition in there.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET *you can't just throw a random condition in there* Are you sure about that?

Comment: @PetSerAl You can in the argument to `switch` of course but cases have to be constants.

Comment: So, if I write it like this: `case _ when randomCondition():` it will not work? @BradleyDotNET

Comment: @PetSerAl There's some pattern matching allowed in C#7 (notice that `when` keyword!) which I'll admit I'm not familiar enough with to know all the rules around. That's not a traditional `switch` though :)

Answer (score 1):

The `switch` statement works by comparing the value you pass in to a list of alternatives you provide. So, you can do:

```
switch (a < b)
{
    case true:
        // do some stuff
        break;
    case false:
        switch (a > b)
        {
            case true:
                // do other stuff
                break;
            case false:
                // do other other stuff
                break;
        }
        break;
 }
```

but you can't do direct comparisons in the `case` statement because they're already doing a comparison with the value you passed into the original `switch`.

Also, the afore-mentioned example is a poor use case for `switch` as it would be better-handled by an if-else. If your goal is to understand `switch`, my advice would be to try converting an `enum` to some other type based on its values:

```
public enum Color
{
    Red,
    Blue,
    Green,
}

public string ConvertToHexWithIfElse(Color myColor)
{
    if (myColor == Color.Red)
    {
        return "#FF0000";
    }
    else if (myColor == Color.Green)
    {
        return "#00FF00";
    }
    else if (myColor == Color.Blue)
    {
        return "#0000FF";
    }

    return string.Empty;
}

public string ConvertToHexWithSwitch(Color myColor)
{
    switch (myColor)
    {
        case Color.Red:
            return "#FF0000";
        case Color.Blue:
            return "#0000FF";
        case Color.Green:
            return "#00FF00";
        default:
            return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Note that even *this* example is somewhat of a poor use of `switch` because the enum was a forced contrivance used simply to show the usage. IMHO switch doesn't have many actual uses: you either use a dictionary or you use an if-else.

Comment: I mean... ok this answers the actual question but doing this in practice is NOT recommended.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Realized that so I added a _proper_ use of it

Comment: To your last comment, `switch` is very useful when you have some actual logic based on the case (instead of just converting to a value as in your contrived example). You can *always* replace with an if/else but that is more verbose. A dictionary, can be used for the logic case but the syntax is awkward.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Agreed. If there's a function conversion then use that, if there's a type-uniformity and no logic then a dictionary is better and if there are few cases then an if-else would make more sense. The only time I've found I needed a switch case was when working with objects that were something like "I want a value in these three cases but for these other four I need to make method calls" or something similar. Think state machines or automata

Comment: Yep, state machines are a classic example (though to be fair I've typically been better served by the State pattern for those)

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Also agree

Comment: ah, so I'm forcing a function in an improper way.
I'm trying to figure out how if else and switch differs.
I was confused because I read somewhere that I should use switch statement if the condition is more than 2 (if - else) just because it is more readable.
I get it now, thanks a lot guys.

Answer (score 1):

When doing a switch statement each "case" is not supposed to have a conditional in it. Switch statements are designed to "switch" values. Like for example, swapping colors!

```
Color c = (Color) (new Random()).Next(0, 3);
switch (c)
{
    //Value of "c" is red
    case Color.Red:
       Console.WriteLine("Red!");
       break;
    //Value of "c" is green
    case Color.Green:
       Console.WriteLine("Green!");
       break;
    //Value of "c" is blue
    case Color.Blue:
       Console.WriteLine("Blue!");   
       break;
    //"c" is not red, green, or blue, so we default our message to say the color is unknown!
    default:
       Console.WriteLine("The color is not known.");
       break;   
}
```

In each "case" we see if "c" is a specific value, and if not, we have a default in our switch statement to handle the scenario.